# bug in GMS 3.x with Bevelbuttons?

Tags: dialog, dm-script

Is there a bug with GMS 3.x concerning bevelbuttons? I had no problems with these with GMS 2.x.

Here is an example where, pressing one button should set the other button to zero.
I am using GMS 3.1.3

```
Class Dialog_UI : UIFrame
    {

    void Response1(object self)
        {
        self.DLGBevelButtonOn( "Bevell2", 0)
        self.Lookupelement("Bevell2").dlgvalue(0)
        result("Bevell1 was pressed... \n")
        self.ValidateView()     
        }
    void Response2(object self)
        {
        self.DLGBevelButtonOn("Bevell1", 0)
        self.Lookupelement("Bevell1").dlgvalue(0)
        result("Bevell2 was pressed... \n")
        self.ValidateView()
        }

    TagGroup CreateDialog_UI( object self )
        {
        TagGroup Dialog_UI = DLGCreateDialog("test")

        image i := IntegerImage("",1,0,25,25); i= 0; i[2,2,23,23] = 1;
        Image onImage = RGB(0*i,200*i,0*i) // template in green
        Image offImage = RGB(200*i,0*i,0*i)

        taggroup Bevell1 =  DLGCreateDualStateBevelButton("Bevell1",onImage,offImage, "Response1")
        taggroup Bevell2 =  DLGCreateDualStateBevelButton("Bevell2",onImage,offImage, "Response2")

        taggroup Bevellgroup=dlggroupitems(Bevell1,Bevell2).dlgtablelayout(2,1,0)       
        Dialog_UI.dlgaddelement(Bevellgroup)
        return Dialog_UI
        }

        object init(object self)
        {

        return self.super.init(self.CreateDialog_UI())
        }

                // default object constructor

        Dialog_UI( object self )
            {

                self.super.init( self.CreateDialog_UI() )
                number dialogID=self.ScriptObjectGetID()
            }


        // default object destructor

        ~Dialog_UI( object self )
            {
                number dialogID=self.ScriptObjectGetID()
                //result("\nDialog with ID: "+dialogID+" destroyed.")
            }

}
void main()
    {
        object Dialog_UI = Alloc(Dialog_UI).init()      
        Dialog_UI.Display("test")
        Return
    }

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this indeed seems to be a bug.

I can verify the misbehavior with GMS 3.4.0.

Please report it to Gatan using the [Gatan DigitalMicrograph bug/issue reporting form](http://swbugs.gatan.com/loginsolosubmit.htm)

Comment: @DonI Can confirm. The webpage seems to be down right now. :c( The link is correct though. (You can also access it directly from www.gatan.com). Please try again tomorrow...